# How to merge htmlAttributes for Html.ActionLink (MVC3)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I'm going to write a simple helper that wraps Html.ActionLink and adds a certain class attribute to it.
At the moment it looks like:

```
@helper MyActionLink(string text, string action, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
    @Html.ActionLink(text, action, routeValues, new { @class = "MyClass" })
}
```

It actually adds needed @class attribute, but ignores all the passed `htmlAttributes`. So, if being used like

```
@MyActionLink("Item1", "Edit", new { itemId = 1 }, new { @class = "class1" })
```

it outputs

```
<a class="MyClass" href="/Test/Edit?itemId=1">Item1</a>
```

but I want it to have 2 classes: `class="class1 MyClass"`

How can I merge those htmlAttributes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this snippet

```
@helper MyActionLink(string text, string action, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var attributes = (IDictionary<string, object>) HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    object cssClass;
    if(attributes.TryGetValue("class", out cssClass) == false)
    {
        cssClass = "";
    }
    attributes["class"] = cssClass + " MyClass";

    @Html.ActionLink(text, action, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), attributes)
}
```

Comment: thanks! Nice to know that RouteValueDictionary's ctor accepts and parses objects.

Comment: I've just seen sources and advise to use `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes` for convertion, because it does some conversion on object property names (such as replace `_` with `-`)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved simply appending  tag in jquery script like this,

```
$("#linkID").html("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-gear'/>"+$("#linkID").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit simpler than hazzik's answer:

```
@helper MyActionLink(string text, string action, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var htmlAttr = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(this.ViewData["htmlAttributes"]);

    htmlAttr["class"] = ("MyClass " + htmlAttr["class"]).Trim();

    @Html.ActionLink(text, action, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), htmlAttr)
}
```

Comment: I guess this.ViewData["htmlAttributes"]) should be htmlAttributes.